# I need get especific parametres(date, month, year) from value selected in ion-datetime

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

When in get the value from ion-date time and print it in console only be print a string. How can i get specific values(date, month, year) from selected value?

this is my code:

```
fecha_nacimiento:Date;
public ageFromDOB($dateOfBirth) {
console.log($dateOfBirth);
}
```

HTML:

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-label position="floating">Fecha de nacimiento</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime type="date" displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" min="1920-03-14" max="2019-12-31"  
 [(ngModel)]="userre.fecha_nacimiento" (ionChange)="ageFromDOB($event)"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public ageFromDOB($dateOfBirth) {
    console.log($dateOfBirth);
    console.log(new Date($dateOfBirth.detail.value).getFullYear());
    console.log(new Date($dateOfBirth.detail.value).getDate());
    console.log(new Date($dateOfBirth.detail.value).getMonth() + 1); // month value has index 0 so add 1 to it.

  }
```